# Google App Engine conditional Field Expressions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, full-text-search

Is it possible to have a search api FieldExpression with a condition?

something like ->

```
search.FieldExpression(name='adjusted_x','Not (x = someValue) x / 2)'
```

Thus, only dividing those values for x that do not equal someValue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as documented at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/options#Python_Writing_expressions , the "language" for expressions in the search API is very strictly limited -- "Expressions involving Number fields can use the arithmetical operators (+, -, *, /) and the built-in numeric functions" min, max, log, abs, pow, count -- that's all; no conditional operators or functions are provided.

I would recommend entering a feature request at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list , ideally supported with a sample use case showing compelling usefulness for the desired feature.

I think the feature would ideally require two sub-features: some comparison operator or function (though if just for equality one could use subtraction, with 0 indicating equality and != 0 inequality), and mostly some conditional operator or function (either with operator syntax like's C ternary operator `cond?iftrue:iffalse`, or function syntax like SQL's `IF` function, `IF(cond, iftrue, iffalse)`, would, I believe, be fine).

Comment: Thanks, Alex, it's a dissapointment to be honest, I was trying to avoid having to do a result by result comparison on the results of the search api query, but if what you say is correct, and I'm sure it is, I'm not going to avoid that. I'll put a feature request in for the future.